# How to compile Freetype (2) and Harfbuzz (with visual studio) to make them work together?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, extern

I have found good documentations on this known problem of compiling Freetype related to Harfbuzz: http://www.gregwessels.com/dev/2017/05/02/freetype-harfbuzz.html and here [44184890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184890/compiling-freetype/49782391#49782391)

But they seem obsolet nowadays: freetype-2.9 with harfbuzz-1.7.6

Here is my way compiling:

- download [Freetype tarball](https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.9.tar.bz2)
- extract the tarball...
- open builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.sln
- it should already Generate well (as a dll)
- download [Harfbuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/harfbuzz/release/harfbuzz-1.7.6.tar.bz2)
- extract the tarball next to freetype...
- run `cmake ./` at root level to obtain a `.sln`
- it must already Generate well (as lib)

At this point you have 2 separate libs not working together which means:

**Freetype will not open GSUB scripts of your fonts.** (or maybe I am wrong)

To do so, I need help! I also need confirmations!!!

Is seems to be needed to enable the use of Harfbuzz in Freetype at compile time; I  have found a precompiler directive called `FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ`

But when activating it, I have some compile link errors when using both libs in a third project:

```
autofit.obj : error LNK2019: external symbol not found _hb_ft_font_create referenced in function _af_face_globals_new
```

Good to know, `hb_ft_font_create` is an extern function in harfbuzz.

So it seems to be a cyclic extern problem... I certainly don't have the good config at a point, but I have browsed many docs and helps, found nothing...

-- edit --
After both pojects decompression, you have normaly to obtain such a tree:

```
.
├── freetype-2.9
│   ├── autogen.sh
│   ├── builds
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── windows
│   │       └── vc2010    <<<< The .sln to use is in here
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt    <<<< It is also good to obtain proper sln
│   ├── configure
│   ├── devel
│   │   ├── ft2build.h
│   │   └── ftoption.h
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── freetype
│   │   └── ft2build.h
│   ├── ...
│   ├── objs
│   │   ├── freetype.dll
│   │   ├── freetype.lib
│   │   ├── README
│   │   └── Win32
│   ├── README
│   ├── README.git
│   └── src
└── harfbuzz-1.7.6
    ├── ...
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    ├── CMakeLists.txt   <<<< The cmake project to obtain proper sln is this one
    ├── compile
    ├── ...
    ├── COPYING
    ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
    ├── Debug
    │   ├── harfbuzz.lib
    │   ├── harfbuzz-subset.lib
    │   └── ...
    ├── depcomp
    ├── docs
    ├── gtk-doc.make
    ├── harfbuzz.sln
    ├── harfbuzz.vcxproj
    ├── ...
    ├── main.dir
    │   └── Debug
    ├── NEWS
    ├── README
    ├── README.python
    ├── RELEASING.md
    ├── replace-enum-strings.cmake
    ├── RUN_TESTS.vcxproj
    ├── RUN_TESTS.vcxproj.filters
    ├── src
    │   ├── *.hh
    │   └── *.cc
    ├── test
    ├── THANKS
    ├── TODO
    ├── util
    └── Win32
        └── Debug
```

Comment: please list the steps you took which you refereed to as: `extract and so on...`

Comment: I have added a shortend dump of my tree after uncompressing sources side by side. I have used 7zip to do so, but I guess it is equivalent to classical `tar -xvf ...`

Comment: The solution seems to compile freetype normaly (no change at all, take it as it is) but modify harfbuzz's CMakeFiles.txt (or CMakeCache already built) to activate the link freetype <- harfbuzz (but not in the other direction).

Comment: I am able to obtain what I want : compile freetype from sln or from cmake. And activate in harfbuzz freetype usage (line `option(HB_HAVE_FREETYPE "Enable freetype interop helpers" ON)` ).
But I also use a hack, adding in harfbuzz `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2`, `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build`, `FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DEBUG` and `FREETYPE_LIBRARY_RELEASE` 
Normaly, I should not do that... how can I configure freetype and/or harfbuzz to use this "LIBRARY" stuff normaly ? Cmake is so confusing in its notions.

Comment: cyclical! https://gist.github.com/roxlu/0108d45308a0434e27d4320396399153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or configure harfbuzz like `--with-freetype=no --with-fontconfig=no` to avoid circular deps...I think so anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Just use https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/ to install both and don't look back :) Both HarfBuzz and Freetype have a port there and are well supported.

About the cyclic dependency, FreeType to HarfBuzz dependency is not a must think to have. `vcpkg` handles HarfBuzz to FreeType dependency and that is what most project will need.

Comment: Thank you, I am reading about `vcpkg`... looks great, but it is another Microsoft only technology. I use to dream harfbuzz and freetype (open libs), very related projects have provided some tech to compile as I want... Sadly, it is not well documented. vcpkg will be my next option for now. I always try to be FULL plateform supportive in my first approch.

Comment: My dependency is from HarfBuzz to FreeType, not in the other way. (Harfbuzz loads objects prepared by Freetype.) I have forsake my first approch to have a cyclic dependency (which looks also possible and needed for some projects).

Comment: Yes, as I said. Even Chrome don't have FreeType to HarfBuzz dependency, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=694137 so as just said use vcpkg :) But if you don't like to use vcpkg, use cmake project file of both projects, this is outdated but used to work https://github.com/ebraminio/glcourse/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: This is not viable. Freetype requires extensive configuration in ftoption.h when built.